# Bug with AlphaComposite.Clear it thinks its background is black

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I am developing a paint app that has transparent Buffered Image. One of the tasks i need to do it to implement a bucketFill Function. I have succeeded in doing so however i cannot do bucket fill operations with black color, because onClick event returns a point and when you check the color of this point its black...program thinks its already all black and returns. It works with all other colors. Any idea how to by pass this problem.

Below it the code that was simplified to demonstrate the problem i have. You can actually run it and it will work.

Paint Main is here

```
public class Paint extends JFrame {
private final int WIDTH = 200;
private final int HEIGHT = 200;

private final Canvas canvas;
private final RightPanel rightPanel;

public Paint() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Paint");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    this.canvas = new Canvas(this);
    this.rightPanel = new RightPanel(canvas);

    this.canvas.setListeners(new BucketFillListener(canvas));
    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    new Paint();
}

public int getWIDTH() {
    return WIDTH;
}

public int getHEIGHT() {
    return HEIGHT;
}

public Canvas getCanvas() {
    return canvas;
}

public RightPanel getRightPanel() {
    return rightPanel;
}
```

}

Canvas Holds Buffered Image

```
public class Canvas extends JComponent {

private final BufferedImage image;
private BucketFillListener listener;

private final Settings settings;

private final int imageWidth = 800;
private final int imageHeight = 800;
private final Paint paint;

public Canvas(Paint paint) {
    this.paint = paint;

    image = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);

    setClearBackground(image);

    this.setSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    this.settings = new Settings();

}

public BucketFillListener getListener() {
    return listener;
}

public Settings getSettings() {
    return settings;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    paint.repaint();
}

public void setClearBackground(BufferedImage image) {
    final BufferedImage img = image;
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
    // g2.setColor(Color.white); // sets white background
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

public void setListeners(BucketFillListener listener) {
    if (this.listener != null) {
        this.removeMouseListener(this.listener);
        this.removeMouseMotionListener(this.listener);
    }

    this.listener = listener;
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this.listener);
    this.addMouseListener(this.listener);
}

public int getImageWidth() {
    return imageWidth;
}

public int getImageHeight() {
    return imageHeight;
}

public Paint getPaint() {
    return paint;
}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return image;
}
```

}
Bucket fill listener does the actuall bucket fill

```
public class BucketFillListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

private final Stack<Point> stack;
private final Canvas canvas;
private int x, y;

public BucketFillListener(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.stack = new Stack<Point>();
    this.canvas = canvas;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    final BufferedImage img = canvas.getImage();
    final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    g2.setColor(canvas.getSettings().getColor());
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    final Color initColor = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
        System.out.println(initColor);
if (initColor.equals(g2.getColor())) {
            return;
        }
    boolean left, right;
    int tempY;

    stack.push(new Point(x, y));
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        final Point p = stack.pop();
        final int activeX = (int) p.getX();
        final int activeY = (int) p.getY();

        tempY = activeY;

        while (tempY >= 0 && initColor.equals((new Color(img.getRGB(activeX, tempY))))) {
            --tempY;

        }
        tempY++;

        left = right = false;
        final int width = img.getWidth();
        final int height = img.getHeight();

        while (tempY < height && initColor.equals(new Color(img.getRGB(activeX, tempY)))) {
            g2.drawLine(activeX, tempY, activeX, tempY);

            canvas.repaint();

            if (!left && activeX > 0 && initColor.equals(new Color(img.getRGB(activeX - 1, tempY)))) {
                stack.add(new Point(activeX - 1, tempY));
                left = true;
                // System.out.println("LEFT " + initColor + "==" + new
                // Color(img.getRGB(activeX - 1, tempY)));
            } else if (left && activeX > 0 && !initColor.equals(new Color(img.getRGB(activeX - 1, tempY)))) {
                left = false;
            }

            if (!right && activeX < width - 1 && initColor.equals(new Color(img.getRGB(activeX + 1, tempY)))) {
                stack.add(new Point(activeX + 1, tempY));
                right = true;
                // System.out.println("RIGHT " + initColor + "==" + new
                // Color(img.getRGB(activeX + 1, tempY)));
            } else if (right && activeX < width - 1 && !initColor.equals(new Color(img.getRGB(activeX + 1, tempY)))) {
                right = false;
            }
            tempY++;
        }
        // System.out.println(i++);
    }
    canvas.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("entered");
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("ex5ted");
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("pressed");
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("released");

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("dragged");
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // System.out.println("moved");
}
```

}

Right Hand tool panel that has color, bucket fill and clear options

```
public class RightPanel extends JPanel {

private final JButton bucketFill;

private final JButton colorButton, clear;

private final Canvas canvas;

public RightPanel(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    this.clear = new JButton("Clear");

    this.bucketFill = new JButton(new ImageIcon("src/charnetskaya/paint/BucketFill.jpg"));
    this.bucketFill.setSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
    this.bucketFill.setBorder(null);
    this.bucketFill.setBorderPainted(false);
    this.bucketFill.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    this.bucketFill.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    this.colorButton = new JButton("   ");
    this.colorButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    this.add(colorButton);

    this.add(bucketFill);
    this.add(clear);

    this.colorButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this));
    this.clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(this));
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    private final RightPanel rightPanel;

    private ButtonListener(RightPanel rightPanel) {
        this.rightPanel = rightPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (event.getSource() == colorButton) {
            new ColorChooser(canvas, colorButton);
        } else if (event.getSource() == clear) {
            canvas.setClearBackground(canvas.getImage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

below is not so important code
Settings that hold setting for the entire app

```
public class Settings {
private Color color;
private Stroke stroke;
private int strokeSize;

public Settings() {
    this.strokeSize = 3;
    this.color = Color.BLACK;
    this.stroke = new BasicStroke(strokeSize, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, 0);
}

public void applySettings(Graphics2D g) {

    g.setColor(color);
    g.setStroke(stroke);
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public Stroke getStroke() {
    return stroke;
}

public void setStroke(Stroke stroke) {
    this.stroke = stroke;
}

public int getStrokeSize() {
    return strokeSize;
}

public void setStrokeSize(int strokeSize) {
    this.strokeSize = strokeSize;
    this.stroke = new BasicStroke(strokeSize, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, 0);
}
```

}

Color Chooser Frame to change colors

```
public class ColorChooser extends JFrame {

private final Canvas canvas;
private final JButton colorButton;

private final JButton selectButton;

private final JColorChooser chooser;

private Color color;

public ColorChooser(Canvas canvas, JButton colorButton) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.colorButton = colorButton;

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setSize(300, 300);

    this.selectButton = new JButton("Select");
    this.selectButton.addActionListener(new SelectButtonListener());

    this.chooser = new JColorChooser();
    this.chooser.add(selectButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.add(chooser);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private class SelectButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        color = chooser.getColor();
        canvas.getSettings().setColor(color);
        colorButton.setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

}

On the image you can see that bucket fill works with any other color but black
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this line to get the color of the current image pixel in your `mouseClicked()` event listener:

```
final Color initColor = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
```

Note the documentation of this constructor of `Color`:

> `Color(int rgb)`
>
> Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified
>   combined RGB value consisting of the red component in bits 16-23, the
>   green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

So it takes the image, drops the alpha component, and gives you an opaque color value. So, if the pixel has `alpha=0,r=0,g=0,b=0`, you'll get `alpha=255,r=0,g=0,b=0` - which happens to be the color black.

In order to avoid this, you should use the constructor that allows you to get the alpha value:

> `Color(int rgba, boolean hasalpha)`
>
> Creates an sRGB color with the specified combined RGBA value
>   consisting of the alpha component in bits 24-31, the red component in
>   bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component
>   in bits 0-7.

That is:

```
final Color initColor = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y), true);
```

This will return a color with the alpha byte set to 0 (assuming your image is completely transparent), which is distinct from `Color.BLACK`.